# how to get Advertising ID in Nokia-x

Tags: android, google-play-services, nokiax

Does nokiax has advertising id concept?

Earlier i was using below code to fetch [Advertising Id](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/id.html) android device application but i am not sure how to do same in nokiax.

Does nokiax has some other alternate for it.

```
info = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context);
adId = info.getId();
optOut = info.isLimitAdTrackingEnabled();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Nokia X specific advertising solution, thus no specific API for any Id generation also.

As the AdvertisingIdClient is part of Google Services API package, it is not supported by the Nokia X.

Basically you can use any advertising solution which does not rely on any Google service, or any other API which is not supplied with the APK (unless they are part of AOSP, or Nokia X platform of course).